# jquery with css transition, some time it not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gL38G/

```
$(function () {

    $(document.body).on('click', '.testA', function () {
        $('.partA').show().css('left', '200px');
    })
        .on('click', '.testB', function () {
        $('.partB').show();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.partB').css('left', '200px');
        }, 50);
    })
        .on('click', '.reset', function () {
        $('div[class*=part]').css('left', 0).hide();
    });
});
```

So I have to add a delay to do some other transition.

Is there a good way to fix this ?

And how do I know the transition is over, I wanner use transition like jquery animate complete event.

Comment: For callbacks, http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transition-callbacks/ explains how to bind to the complete event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using setTimeout use [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

The syntax is something like this

`$('.partB').show().delay(50).css('left', '200px');`

Or if you want it to fire when the show event is finished look at the documentation for [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) it accepts a "complete" callback parameter.

In that case you would use

```
$('.partB').show(0, function() {
    $('.partb').css('left', '200px');
});
```

where 0 is the duration and the function parameter is the "complete" callback.

Comment: Seems delay is not works, I have add other function to do it.

Comment: If you want to run the 'left' animation when the show event if completed then use the "complete" parameter for the 'show' event.

http://jsfiddle.net/gL38G/2/